# Grant adb always-access to other computers

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

how can I grant adb access for my android device to my all computers without connecting to every one and press allow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every computer when connect to a device via adb writhe a code to the android device so you can copy this code from one device what you connect and paste it to the new device
the location for the place where the code was save is

```
/data/misc/adb/adb_keys
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Just copy the adb key generated on PC side to all PCs and you are done. On PC side the key is easily accessible where as on Android side as in your answer you need a rooted device and a special app to place the key, as you don't have adb access yet.

Comment: witch key is generate on a pc?

Comment: In your user home `.android/adbkey` and `.android/adbkey.pub` These are the keys that identify a PC on ADB level, thus these are the keys the phone recognize and saves if you allow an adb connection on the phone.